# Couldn't find that process type (web)

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

So I'm doing a university group project and we are demonstrating tomorrow. It's a flask API and I'm hosting with Heroku. At first I got this error

`code=H14 desc="No web processes running"`

After looking around I found a solution to scale dynos with :

```
heroku ps:scale web=1
```

Which in turn failed, resulting in this error

```
Couldn't find that process type (web)
```

I have no idea what is going wrong. My Procfile is named correctly and updated (no .txt at the end). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My Procfile:

```
web:gunicorn api_prediction:medi-ai
```

Where "api-prediction" is the python file to run and "medi-ai is the project name"

Answer (score 0):

Example for the Procfile

```
#filename: Procfile
web: gunicorn runserver:app --log-file=-
```

Example for the gunicorn

```
# filename: run.gunicorn.sh
gunicorn -b :5000 --access-logfile - --error-logfile - runserver:app
```

Also install gunicorn and dont miss the requirements.txt file too.

```
pip install gunicorn
```

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

If this doesn't resolved your issue please reply.